# error: cannot find symbol resultset

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I am really stuck at this...I am trying to convert Result Set into string and this is my code :

```
QueryExecution qExec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(s, ds) ;
       ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect() ;
       //String x=rs.toString();
       String[] arr = null;

        while (rs.next()) {
            String em = (String)rs.getString(0);
           arr = em.split("\n");
           for (int i =0; i < arr.length; i++){
              subjectoutput.setText(arr[i]); 
           }
       }
```

and it gives error:

```
JavaApplication2.java:137: error: incompatible types
            while (rs.next()) {
                          ^
  required: boolean
  found:    QuerySolution
JavaApplication2.java:138: error: cannot find symbol
                String em = (String)rs.getString(0);
                                      ^
  symbol:   method getString(int)
  location: variable rs of type ResultSet
2 errors
```

my query result is this:

```
    ----------------------------
| x                                           
================================================
| <<SEMA-CR-3-4MHV9RJ@bounce.oracle-mail.com>> |
------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which compiler are you using? Is this the reql code? It works just fine...

Comment: Try this: `java.sql.ResultSet rs = qExec.execSelect();` then put the rest of your code. Does the error message change?

Comment: Actually i am running sparql query so I cannot use that...any other solution??

Comment: well I did !! but still errors..

Comment: yup actually I imported the ResultSet already

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged with [tag:oracle].  the ResultSet here is a Jena ResultSet, not a SQL resultset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use `ResultSet` as if it were from JDBC. But you're using [Jena ARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/index.html) here. This isn't a JDBC implementation and it doesn't follow that API. `QueryExecution` is [here](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/QueryExecution.html), and `ResultSet` is [here](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/index.html).

For this `ResultSet` object, you should call `hasNext()` to see if there is another record, and `next()` to fetch the record. So your loop might look more like this:

```
while (rs.hasNext()) {
    QuerySolution qs = rs.next();
    ... // Do something with qs
}
```

`ResultSet.getString(int)` is a JDBC function, and there's no such function on either `ResultSet` or `QuerySolution`, so I couldn't tell you exactly how to get the information that you want out of the result set.

Comment: that helped me a lot!! but I am still don't know how to convert it to string?

Comment: Take a look at the API documentation.

Comment: @user3654540 A result set provides a set of query solutions.  Each solution binds a set of variables.  You'd need to get the result for a particular variable from a query solution, and then convert that to a string.  The documentation that Kenster linked to should be descriptive enough to figure out how to do this.